# Structure generating a dynamic invoice overview, based on input form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

for an ecommerce-like feature, I'm trying to create an invoice overview of all selected items (name, quantity, total price).

**Example:**
User clicks on product it wants to book, then gets an options form with options (`option.name` and `option_quantity`) related to the product. if the quantity is above one, the invoice overview of selected items should update.

**Current approach:** My current approach is to create all option lines in the invoice overview already and hide them. Once an `option_quantity` is updated, the option line changes its display to `flex` and thereby is shown in the invoice overview.

- Note: the form `option_quantity` has an `id` with the `option.id` and the invoice line related to the option has a `class` with that same `option.id`, such that I can link them
- No idea yet how to get the total price for that invoice line for the respective line of that option.

**Questions**

- My approach seems to be quite cumbersome and I was wondering if there is a better way to dynamically adjust an invoice overview based on user input.
- If not, how can I get/insert the total price for an option in the invoice overview.

**Other** I have helper methods, to calculate option prices for the rails app, but not sure if this can help as I use javascript to update prices.

**Code**

form

```
#where user sees all options belonging to a product_category and can fill in option_quantity
<%= simple_form_for [@booking] do |f|%>
<%= f.simple_fields_for :booking_options do |o| %>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-5 border-bottom mb-3">
          <%= o.object.option.name %>
          <%= o.input :option_id, as: :hidden %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-7 border-bottom mb-3">
          <b> <%= number_to_currency(online_booking_option_price(o.object.option, Date.parse(arrival), Date.parse(departure)), :unit=> @currency ) %></b>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-7 border-bottom mb-3">
          <%= o.input :option_quantity, label: false, collection: 1..20, :input_html => { :value => 0, :id => o.object.option.id, :class => "option_quantity" } %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
[...]
```

invoice overview (on same page as the form above)

```
#invoice overview
[...name, quantity, price on product_category...]

#invoice lines related to options
<% @product_category.options.each do |option| %>
      <div class="online-booking-price-item online-booking-price-item-option-container <%= option.id %>">
        <div class="online-booking-price-item-name">
          <%= option.name %>
        </div>
        <div class="online-booking-price-item-price online-booking-price-item-option-price">

#below the wrong price, as this is the price for one quantity of option and does not take into account the given input.
          <%= number_to_currency(online_booking_option_price(option, Date.parse(arrival), Date.parse(departure)), :unit=> @currency ) %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

script to get and insert option_price in overview

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $('.online-booking-price-item-option-container').hide();


    var options = document.getElementsByClassName('option_quantity');

    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        options.item(i).addEventListener('change', (event) => {
          var optionId = event.target.id

          document.getElementsByClassName(optionId)[0].style.display = "flex" ;
        })
    }
  });
</script>
```

app/helpers/online_booking_helper.rb

```
#price for one option for the respective arrival and departure
def online_booking_option_price(option, arrival, departure)
[...]
end

#price for one option for the respective arrival and departure incl. quatity
def online_booking_option_price(option, arrival, departure, quantity)
[...]
end
``
```

Comment: If you have working code and are looking to improve it you should post on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Thanks Chris, unfortunately the code is not working yet. (See also 2nd bullit point under header Questions). For clarity purposes, I added an extra explanation in the invoice overview on which part is not working.

Comment: I'd do this: user clicks submit -> form is posted via ajax -> RoR keeps order items in session, adds the new item, compiles and sends back invoice table data and total(s) as JSON -> ajax success replaces table with updated version

Comment: The alternative is to use data attributes to pass a machine readable version of the prices (integer in lowest monetary unit such as cents) and add it up in javascript. But @ChrisG's suggestion is much better except I would actually store it in the database instead having stuff floating around in the session.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! @ChrisG, would that mean that I need to insert html generated by javascript code as well?

Comment: Well, you can send back final HTML of course and insert that (and given that you're using RoR templates, that's a valid option) but people usually separate content and presentation, thus you'd send back the data only, then present it buy building HTML from it and inserting that.